# How can I use skyfied to convert SGP4 TEME coordinate to ECEF?

Tags: python, skyfield, sgp4

I want to plot the satellite tracking on a map. So I use SGP4 1.4 with python .Input the TLE data, but the outdata is not what I want. So I want to convert the output data to the ECEF data and get the longitude and latitude.

I know the skyfied can convert TEME to ECEF but Idon't know how to use it.

https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/blob/master/skyfield/sgp4lib.py

and I use the skyfield met the error:

```py
from skyfield.api import load
ts=load.timescale()
```

error is:

```
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skyfield\iokit.py", line 213, in timescale
    data = self('deltat.data')

File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skyfield\iokit.py", line 166, in __call__
    download(url, path, self.verbose)

File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skyfield\iokit.py", line 329, in download
    raise IOError('cannot get {0} because {1}'.format(url, e))

IOError: cannot get http://maia.usno.navy.mil/ser7/deltat.data because <urlopen error [Errno 10060] >
```

Comment: Library `skyfield` trying to download file `deltat.data` from web site (link in last line) and can't do it. Try to check your Internet connection or download `deltat.data` file and put it into your working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by add some code.
In the iokit.py 'function download() 335 line

```
 try:
    print (url)  #original

    try:
        connection = urlopen(url)
    except:
       import urllib2
       user_agent ='"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36"' #cxh
       headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
       proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({}) 
       opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy) 
       urllib2.install_opener(opener) 
       req ,= urllib2.Request(url, headers = headers) 
       response = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
       connection= response
       print ('get data successfully')

except Exception as e:
    raise IOError('cannot get {0} because {1}'.format(url, e))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following link, you can use the SGP4 Python version which returns the satellite's state vector in three coordinate systems i.e. TEME, ECEF, and ECI. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358351066_SGP4_Python_code